# How to copy an object in an array in JS based on the proprtey of the object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

var myArray = [];
var myObject = {
    Quantity : 5,
    key2 : 'value2'
};

myArray.push(myObject);

How can create multiple objects based on the property Quantity in myArray[0];
i.e Array should have 5 objects with  the copy of myObject. unfortunately i cannot push it 5 times as there is a logic to have myArray with only one object. After the logic is executed the myArray should have the copied objects.

```
myArray = [{ Quantity : 5,key2 : 'value2'},
           { Quantity : 5,key2 : 'value2'},
           { Quantity : 5,key2 : 'value2'},
           { Quantity : 5,key2 : 'value2'},
           { Quantity : 5,key2 : 'value2'}]
```

Comment: what's your problem? you mean you can't push it 5 times?

Comment: how can i copy object multiple times and assign to array again?

Comment: You have logic "to have array with only one object", but you want 5?

Comment: Yes , The array should have 5 objects finally. Initially only one object , Some logic is executed , after logic execution array should have 5 objects which is copy of object 1

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague. From what's mentioned, you can do something like the following:

```
var myArray = []; 
var myObject = { Quantity : 5, key2 : 'value2' };
myArray.push(myObject);
[1,2,3,4].forEach((i) => {
    myArray[i] = Object.assign({},myObject);
});
console.log(myArray);
```